# Merge 3 columns in CSV using Perl in the same CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

I have below 3 columns in *CSV* file and I want to merge them in the first column itself using *Perl* script.

Column 1: 32:
Column 2: annotate
Column 3: test

Output should be in Column 1 as :
32:annotate test

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

[Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) is in my opinion the way to go. Less error prone than any homemade solution based on `split`, regexp and whatever, fast and its interface should make the solution to your problem trivial.